# Close votes limited to 20 under "review" but can still vote on per question

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

Yesterday I maxed out my close votes for the day, and in fact still have three hours until the close vote under the review tab opens again. But as I was reading a off topic question, I clicked close in the question and my vote was taken.

Is this a bug?

[image: close vote count]

Comment: I think you should have 24 votes per day (see http://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

Comment: @Sklivvz - There may be a mismatch then in max votes from the review tab and the privileges page?

Comment: They are two different things (close vote reviews and close votes), they don't necessarily have the same number - I'll double check - but for one, not all reviews end with a close vote cast, and surely the number of close vote you can cast is fixed.

Comment: @Sklivvz - ahh....that makes sense now. Vote to close is not the same as review to close.....Sorry, I got confused there :)

Comment: I think that this should go under [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I am wrong, but here is my hypothesis from my experiences:

You can review 20 posts per review queue. However, you have 24 close votes a day. The system took your vote because it was not in the review queue for the day, but it still counts towards your 24 close vote per day limit. In the review queue, both the close and not close options count as a review (skips don't), but only those that you actually give a vote to close response to actually count toward your close votes per day.

I agree that the fact that the review queue entry page says "20 Close Votes" and that is misleading, but that is perhaps because "Close Votes" is the name of the review queue. This should be made more clear that it is in fact the review queue and not close votes overall.